# Does an Empiricist Investigator HAVE to use Intelligence for skills?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, ability-scores, archetype

I'm going to be playing a Dex-based Empiricist, whose Dex will have one modifier higher than Int in some cases, plus Extracts. But, on the [PFSRD for Empiricist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/archetypes/paizo-investigator-archetypes/empiricist/):

> ...an empiricist uses his Intelligence modifier instead of the skill’s typical ability for all Disable Device, Perception, Sense Motive, and Use Magic Device checks. ...

The wording explicitly avoids saying "May use", instead opts to just say "Uses", and that "All" was included makes me think that you cannot. Does this imply that you *must* use your Intelligence modifier for all of them, or can one be switched if you have a better bonus elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### RAW, yes.

As you wrote, it's not "may use", "can choose to use" or any equivalent thing: it's "uses". It means the Empiricist doesn't have the choice, he has to use its Intelligence.

However it is supposed to be a beneficial class feature, and because of that most of the DMs will let you ignore it when it doesn't benefit you. Speak to your DM.